# Yii2 открывается только главная страница

Tags: php, yii2, debian, vps

сайт находится на VPS, первый раз не правильно настроил сервер, а именно с виртуальными хостами не мог совладать, по этому сайт был залит в корень и прекрасно работал. Не много разобравшись, правильно сконфигурировал сервер, залил сайт и теперь открывается только главная страница, при переходе на другие страницы получаю 404.
Конфигурация апач:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin midtofeed@gmail.com
        ServerName parkaukcyjny.pl
        ServerAlias www.parkaukcyjny.pl
        DocumentRoot /var/www/parkaukcyjny.pl/public_html/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.mydomain.ru
        ServerAdmin midtofeed@gmail.com
        ServerName parkaukcyjny.pl
        ServerAlias www.parkaukcyjny.pl
        DocumentRoot /var/www/parkaukcyjny.pl/public_html/
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
            #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Расположение файлов Yii2, все файлы из папки web залиты в папку public_html, остальные файлы фреймворка находятся на уровень выше в папке parkaukcyjny.pl. 
В папке parkaukcyjny.pl лежит файл .htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /public_html/index.php
</IfModule>
```

В папке public_html лежит файл .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

В настройка urlManager ничего не указано:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
```

Перезаливал файлы, менял .htaccess, ничего не помогает, надеюсь уже только на вас.

Answer (score 0):

И так проблема оказалась очень просто решаема. В файле конфигурации Апач

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Нужно было поменять

```
AllowOverride none
```

На

```
AllowOverride All
```

Для конкретной папки у меня это было

```
<Directory /var/www>
Options Indexes Includes
AllowOverride none
Allow from all
</Directory>
```